# How to quantify polygon as potential exposure to points

Tags: raster, r, spatial-statistics

I have a set of points and a series of ellipses (polygons) that I can overlay on the points. Let's say that the ellipses represent where an individual spends most of their time—an activity space. And the points represent something bad like crime (it does not in my case, but this makes for a clean example).

I want to use the activity space (polygons) and the "crime data" (points) to quantify someone's potential *exposure* to an environmental factor like crime.

I don't do much GIS work, so I'd like to get help thinking through it conceptually (and maybe technically at a later point).

I can think of 3 ways of characterizing the activity space in terms of exposure to the points:

1. Count how many points fall inside of the ellipse.

[image]

2. Create buffers around the points of a certain size and count how many buffers intersect with the ellipse.

[image]

3. Create kernel density estimates and sum the density values inside the ellipse.

[image]

1. Counting points inside the ellipse is clean but it ignores points in close proximity but outside of the ellipse.
2. Counting intersections with buffers overcomes this limitation a bit but still lacks a way to capture nearby but non-overlapping buffers.
3. The density appears to capture more information, but it's not as intuitive.

Thoughts about these options? Are there better options not represented here?

Comment: You can do all the above, but the problem is that your fundamental interest "the extent to which each ellipse is potentially influenced by the points" isn't very well explained. What does "influenced" mean here? What would a pattern of points and ellipses look like if there was zero "influence", or if there was very strong "influence"? Are the points influencing the position, size, angle, eccentricity of the ellipses?

Comment: Thanks for the question. In this case, the ellipses represent where someone spends time—an activity space (this one is fake). Let's say that the points represent something bad like crimes (they don't, but this will make the example easy). Activity spaces will vary in size, shape, and location for individuals. Can we characterize each person's space by its relation to an environmental factor like the locations of crimes? Distance is important, but so is intensity. Density seems to capture both, but I'm hoping to get advice on this conceptual point.

Comment: Maybe to add: this is an attempt to measure potential exposure to something like crime based on where someone spends most of their time.

Comment: All those methods would seem to broadly correlate with each other and all satisfy the condition that if there's no points near the ellipse you get a low measure and if the ellipse is full of points you get a high measure. Which is "best" is a methodological question that we can't answer. Suppose you are fitting a regression model to see if this explains a person's response to "How fearful of crime are you?" given their activity space - you can include all the variables and you might get some information from them. But that's too broad for discussion here.

Comment: Thanks, @Spacedman. Maybe it's a difficult ask. Through further reading I came across IDW as an alternative to kernel density, but that seems better suited for point incidence data whereas I have discrete points that carry no additional information like rates. If readers know other methods to consider I'd be interested in a few leads. Likewise, maybe folks have come across papers discussing pros and cons of count vs interpolated data. I can apply general lessons to my approach.